# ng-if not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I am working on a large Angular app that has to support IE8 and we are starting to run into performance issues.  The home page is making a lot of use of ng-show, but I'd like to be able to completely remove chunks of the dom using ng-if.  When I swap ngIf for ngShow, everything is hidden.  Are there known issues with ng-if and ie8?  We are using Angular version 1.1.5.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example? This is something simple enough that it should work with IE8;  I remember using ng-if with ie8 with 1.2 a while ago.

Comment: I should have noted that we are using 1.1.5. Unfortunately, that is the version we have to stay on for the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get ng-if working by upgrading to 1.2.16, along with angular-route and angular-animate.

Answer (score 1):

[AngularJS has issues with IE](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

> **Internet Explorer Compatibility**
>
> *Note: AngularJS 1.3 is dropping support for IE8. Read more about it on our blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.*
>
> This document describes the Internet Explorer (IE) idiosyncrasies when dealing with custom HTML attributes and tags. Read this document if you are planning on deploying your Angular application on IE8 or earlier.
>
> The project currently supports and will attempt to fix bugs for IE9 and above. The continuous integration server runs all the tests against IE9, IE10, and IE11. See Travis CI and ci.angularjs.org.
>
> We do not run tests on IE8 and below. A subset of the AngularJS functionality may work on these browsers, but it is up to you to test and decide whether it works for your particular app.